# How to use phrase as termfreq term argument

Tags: solr, lucene

I would like to use termfreq to provide the frequency of matching a phrase in a field. Based on looking through a lot of posts hither and yon, I have set up the relevant fieldType for the target field as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
<!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The field is:

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

As a test, I have a text field that contains within it's body the phrase "test document".  Given this setup, the function termfreq(text,"test document") correctly returns 1.  However, if I instead call termfreq(text,"document test"), it returns 0, even though when I use a query of text:"document test", it reports a hit for the document (which is what I want).

So I am confused about how this should work. I would further like to include the proximity operator as part of the termfreq term (something like termfreq(text,"test document"~4)), but I cannot find anyway to get that to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a query, the string you are passing in is a query.  When calling the `termfreq` function, you string you are passing in a *term*, not a query.

A query is parsed for query syntax, and will be analyzed (usually).  Neither happens for a term.  A term is essentially the atomic unit of indexed text, so it will look for *precisely* the term you passed in in the index.

So, for your query, `text:"document test"`, you will be searching for three terms `document test`, `document`, and `test`.  While `document test` is not found in the index, the other two are, so you have a match.  For the termfreq call, you specifically ask it to get the frequency of the single term `document test`, which is 0.

Comment: Aha.  Well, having spent all of two days trying to understand SOLR/LUCENE, I greatly appreciate this prompt answer, so I will not waste any more time trying to divine a way to use termfreq do this.  A collateral question then (if it is appropriate here): is there a way to get the "match count" of any given clause that appears in a query?